# How to delete the book that have been input and how to make the title, language, and name doesn't error if we put space on it?

Tags: c++, stack

Can anyone help me to make a new menu to delete all the books that have been entered? And how to make the title, name, and language can be entered with space?
I've searched other questions about it, many of them using getline. But i don't understand how to use it on class like this.

(Sorry my grammar is bad, i'm not very good in English)

This is the source code that i've been made.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Book {
    int number, year;
    string language, name, title;
    Book * head, * next;
public:
Book (string & name, string & title, int number, string & language, int year) {
head = NULL;
this -> name = name;
this -> title = title;
this -> language = language;
this -> number = number;
this -> year = year;
};
~ Book (void) {
    delete head;
};
void display (void);
void add (void);
void dellete (string&);
};

void Book :: add (void) {
string name, title, language;
int year, number;

cout << endl << "Author:", cin >> name;
cout << "Title:", cin >> title;
cout << "Number of books:", cin >> number;
cout << "Language:", cin >> language;
cout << "Year of publication:", cin >> year;

Book * p = new Book (name, title, number, language, year);
p -> next = head;
head = p;
}

void Book :: display (void) {
Book * p = head;
while (p) {
    cout << "----------------------------- \n";
    cout << "Author:" << p -> name << endl;
    cout << "Title:" << p -> title << endl;
    cout << "Number of books:" << p -> number << endl;
    cout << "Language:" << p -> language << endl;
    cout << "Year of publication:" << p -> year << endl;
    cout << endl;
    p = p -> next;
}
}

int main (int argc, char const ** argv) {

string blank = "";
Book * B = new Book (blank, blank, false, blank, 0);
int opt;
cout << "\nBOOK STACKS \n";
for (;;) {
    cout << "1) Add a book.\n";
    cout << "2) Show all books.\n";
    cout << "3) Exit. \n\n";

    cout << "Options:", cin >> opt;

    switch (opt) {
            case 1:
                B -> add ();
            break;
            case 2:
                B -> display ();
            break;
            case 3:
                exit (0);
            default:
            continue;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Please help me to get the code because it's my mid-test task and i'm still a beginner at programming. Thanks.

Comment: [Read whole lines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: On an unrelated note, your `Book` destructor is most likely wrong (and will probably lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

Comment: What does it mean   `Book` destructor ?

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of `this->` syntax by choosing different names between parameters and members.

Comment: You should separate the concept of a linked list from a Book.  A Book is a single object.  A library contains zero or more books.  A shelf can contain zero or more books.  Rarely do books contain books or point to other books.

Comment: If you need to develop your own linked list, search the internet for "c++ linked list delete node".  Always search before posting.

Comment: Hi @ThomasMatthews thanks for your comment. But i'm still amateur at this topic. Could u please show me the code how i change `this->` syntax and how to seperate the concept? Thanks

Comment: Try this:  `Book(int book_number, int book_year, const std::string& book_language, const std::string& book_name, const std::string& book_title) : number(book_number), year(book_year), language(book_language), name(book_name), title(book_title) { }`

Comment: You could also do this:  `Book(int b_number, int b_year, const std::string& b_language, const std::string& b_name, const std::string& b_title) { number = b_number; year = b_year; language = b_language; name = b_name; title = b_title;}`  Notice how I changed the name of the parameters.

Comment: To separate the concept between a list and a Book:  `class Book_List_Node{Book b; Book_List_Node * previous; Book_List_Node * next;}`  The `Book` is now a member of the `Book_List_Node`.  The `Book_List` could contain a pointer to the head node and contain all the methods of a linked list.  Or you could save yourself some work and use `std::list<Book>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @ThomasMatthews . I'll try the code asap.

Comment: Remember to click the check mark on the answer it was useful.

Comment: ok @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enter data per line, here is an example:

```
class Book
{
    int number;
    int year;
    std::string language
    std::string name;
    std::string title;
  public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Book& b);
//...
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Book& b)
{
  std::string text_line;
  std::getline(input, text_line);
  std::istringstream  text_stream(text_line);
  text_stream >> b.number >> b.year >> b.language >> b.name >> b.title;
  return input;
}
```

If each data item is on a separate line, you could change `operator>>` as:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Book& b)
{
    input >> b.number;
    input >> b.year;
    std::getline(input, b.language);
    std::getline(input, b.name);
    std::getline(input, b.title);
    return input;
}
```

An example input from a file:

```
std::vector<Book> library;
Book b;
while (data_file >> b)
{
    library.push_back(b);
}
```